# How to translate SQL table creation into JPA hibernate autocreation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am struggling with this for hours already.

These are the tables that I want to have created in DB with all the PKs and UQ etc.

```
CREATE  TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (username));

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_role_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  role varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_role_id),
  UNIQUE KEY uni_username_role (role,username),
  KEY fk_username_idx (username),
  CONSTRAINT fk_username FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username));
```

I am not able to translate that into Java Entities with JPA annotation to achieve the same result in DB.

My User object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "test")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Column(name = "birthdate")
private Date birthDate;
@Column(name = "proffesion")
private String profession;
```

And my UserRole object:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;
@OneToOne(targetEntity=User.class)
private String username;
@Column(name="role")
private String role;
```

I have tried many variations of that but none of it did exactly the same thing as the SQL query above.

Comment: and what were the differences from what you want? or is it a quiz question?

Comment: It depends which version I try... usually it creates additional column in `UserRoles` table. Simply I am unable to map `UserRoles` `username` with `User` `username`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation in Java means using the object type of the other side, not stuffing a String in there, so you need to modify `UserRole` to have

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="username")
private User user;
```

instead of field "`username`".

Why you have loads of extra fields (`email`, `birthDate`, `profession`) in `User` that don't appear in the stated table I've no idea ... they are clearly inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it looks like it did what it was supposed, but for some reason my Spring security still doesn't accept it. (and it does accept when I create the tables with the query). The additional data in Java class ... just ignore that.